# throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " msg );

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please  help me in finding the problem

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #save_property_#{result.id} 
>          throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "   msg );

home.js:

```
$(".save_prop").click(function(){
    $('#save_property_#{result.id}').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

view.html.erb

```
<div id="save_property_<%= result.id %>" style="background : #ececef; width :500px; height:100px; display:none;">
<% if (user_signed_in? || current_twitter_user || current_fb_user) %>
    property saved
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in  /", user_session_path %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %>
    to save the property
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: the selector `#save_property_#{result.id}` is the problem, that's not a valid jQuery selector.  You probably need to do DOM traversal to find the `#save_property_XXX` element corresponding to the `.save_prop` element that was clicked. You'll need to show more of the HTML so we can see how they're related.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $('#save_property_result.id').slideToggle();
```

This helped me in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$('#save_property_#{result.id}').slideToggle();
```

with

```
$('#save_property_<%=result.id%>').slideToggle();
```

and change your file name from home.js to home.js.erb

Comment: does the error come on "$('#save_property_<%=result.id%>').slideToggle();" this line?

Comment: there's no error from that line.I think error is from the view div. My functionality is working as expceted.

Comment: I guess you dont have $('#save_property_<%=result.id%>') in your DOM,
 Have it console.log("#save_property_<%=result.id%>") so you can see the result

Comment: No, from by firebug the id chanages dynamically, like this $('#save_property_1') for properpty.id = 1. My functionality is working properly.

Comment: When i click the button toggle comes down as expected, but the page goes to top of the page, and error is shown in the firebug

Comment: I have updated the answer, change your file name from "home.js" to "home.js.erb"

Answer (score 0):

The key is in name of your file - `home.js`
It is not erb or any other rails template files. It is a standalone JavaScript file, which does not know rails syntax or any or your back-end objects. It is compiled on the client-side and server gives it to the browser "as it is"

You have to place that script inside your `erb` file to work like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, Still not working after changing home.js to home.js.erb

Comment: It will never work that way :) Put your script code inside your html.erb file